# Vue js @change parameters are always 0 when uploading a file by clicking on the picture

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/includephone/o9gpb1q8

I am having a problem with @change in input. I'm trying to make an image slider, there should be 4 images on each slide.

**Data**

```
 data: function () {
        return {
            page: [
                {
                    type: 'text',
                    name: 'title-brand',
                    text: '',
                    image: '',
                    preview: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'slider',
                    type:'file',
                    slide:[
                        [
                            {
                                model_name:'',
                                inst:'',
                                item_name:'',
                                item_link:'',
                                image:'',
                                preview:''
                            },
                            {
                                model_name:'',
                                inst:'',
                                item_name:'',
                                item_link:'',
                                image:'',
                                preview:''
                            },
                            {
                                model_name:'',
                                inst:'',
                                item_name:'',
                                item_link:'',
                                image:'',
                                preview:''
                            },
                            {
                                model_name:'',
                                inst:'',
                                item_name:'',
                                item_link:'',
                                image:'',
                                preview:''
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

**Methods**

```
methods: {
        onImageChange(e, parent_index, index, item_index){
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            let vm = this.page[parent_index];
            console.log(`${index}, ${item_index}`);
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e)=>{
                Vue.set(vm.slide[index][item_index], 'image', e.target.result);
            }
            Vue.set(vm.slide[index][item_index], 'preview', URL.createObjectURL(files[0]));
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
        },
        stat(par1, par2){
            console.log(`pat1: ${par1}, par2: ${par2}`);
        }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div v-for="(component, parent_index) in page" v-bind:key="parent_index" class="container-constructor">
    <div v-if="component.name==='slider'" class="data-block slider">
        <div class="body-block">
            <div v-for="(slide, index) in component.slide" v-bind:key="index">
                <div v-for="(item, item_index) in slide" v-bind:key="item_index" class="slider-item">
                    <button type="button" @click="stat(index, item_index)">Click {{index}} {{item_index}}</button>
                    <label for="slider-item-file-1">
                        <img v-if="item.preview.length>1" :src="item.preview" width="160px" height="200px"/>
                        <img v-else src="images/image6.png" width="160px" height="200px"/>
                    </label>
                    <input type="file" @change="onImageChange($event, parent_index, index, item_index)" id="slider-item-file-1"/>
                    <div class="slider-item-info">
                        <input type="text" v-model="item.model_name" name="model-name" placeholder="model name"/>
                        <input type="text" v-model="item.inst" name="instagram-model" placeholder="model inst"/>
                        <div class="item-name">
                            <input type="text" v-model="item.item_name" name="item-name" placeholder="item name"/>
                            <input type="text" v-model="item.inst" name="item-link" placeholder="item link"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What could be the problem that the parameters are not passed correctly and how can this be fixed?
When loading an image, in the onImageChange method, the index and item_index parameters are always 0

Comment: I created a new vue component with the exact code you gave. I had to change vm in your onImageChange method as it was undefined to `this.page[parent_index]` and the code works perfectly. If you are still having issues could you post all your code

Comment: (Note: index will always be 0 as there is only one key that contains an array of all images in the slide array)

Comment: @Hides Sorry, forgot to copy the line with let vm = `this.page [parent_index]` . Can you please tell me why item_index always comes with a value of 0?

Comment: I am unsure what the issue can be without additional information. I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hides/gmdqp8sz/) which contains only the code you have posted and the item_index is outputting correctly. Example: if you uploaded a file using the input next to the button "Click 0 2" the output from `console.log(\`${index}, ${item_index}\`` would be 0, 2.

Comment: @Hides [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/includephone/o9gpb1q8/)
The file should be loaded by clicking on the image on the left. If you load through input, then everything is fine, but when you download a file through a click on the image, item _index is 0

Comment: I see, ok that makes sense. Added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that item_index is always 0 is because the label you have set on the image is linked to the id `slider-item-file-1` which has been set for every file input. An element should have a unique id, in your code you don't so when you click the label it will always access the first occurrence of that id in the body hence you will always get an item_index of 0. If you made the ids dynamic this will fix your problem.

This is also why you will notice that when you click on the bottom image it jumps up to the top of the page because it's going to the first file input with that id.

```
<label :for="'slider-item-file-' + parent_index + '-' + index + '-' + item_index">
      <img v-if="item.preview.length>1" :src="item.preview" width="160px" height="200px"/>
      <img v-else src="images/image6.png" width="160px" height="200px"/>
</label>
<input type="file" @change="onImageChange($event, parent_index, index, item_index)" :id="'slider-item-file-' + parent_index + '-' + index + '-' + item_index"/>
```

Each id will contain the index of each for loop.

Hope this helps